# Image Cell Multiple Binding Format XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

I am making an application with Xamarin Forms. I want the app to display a list view similar to youtube. There is a thumbnail on the left and on the right there is a Video Title with details underneath. Currently, I am only able to place the details on a single line.

***How would I seperate the details into multiple lines within the Image Cell?***

*Currently:*

[image]

Homepage.xaml:

```
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <ListView x:Name="VideoList" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <ImageCell Text = "{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageURL}"/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Videos.cs:

```
    class Videos
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public DateTime Upload_DateTime { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public string Detail
    {

        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}  Views Uploaded: {2} ", Author, Views, Upload_DateTime); //format for details on imagecell
        }
    }


}
```

**NOTE: I have tried the following formats on Videos.cs:**

`return string.Format("{0} - {1}  Views \nUploaded: {2} ", Author, Views, Upload_DateTime);`

`return string.Format("{0} - {1}  Views&#x0a;Uploaded: {2} ", Author, Views, Upload_DateTime);`

Comment: You need to use a ViewCell and define your own layout instead of using the predefined ImageCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jason!

Now I have a grid layout inside of a View Cell. It seems to be exactly what I needed! Next, I will need to correct the formatting to make it look prettier, but for the most part, this question is answered!

[image]

**Homepage.xaml:**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <ListView x:Name="VideoList" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Author_Views}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Uploaded}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```